# How can you use a while loop so the user can open a new text file? Python

Tags: python, while-loop

I want to use a while loop that will give the user an opportunity to open a new text file at the end of the program. Here is the code I have:

```
run_again = "yes"
run_again = run_again.upper().strip()
while run_again == "yes":
    open_file = input("Please enter name of file: ")
    file_name = open(open_file,"r")
    for line in file_name:
        line = line.strip()
        rows = line.split(" ")
        num = rows[0]
        print(num)
    run_again = input("Would you like to open a new file (yes or no)? ")
    if run_again != "yes":
        print("Have a great day!")
```

I've managed to make a while loop work with other code but I can't get it to work with opening text files.

Comment: What's wrong with your code exactly?

Comment: `run_again = run_again.upper().strip()` makes `run_again` equal to `YES`. Then you do `while run_again == "yes":` which is false right off the bat.

Comment: Some things I'd change: You should put the `.upper().strip()` lines inside the loop. You don't need the `if` statement in the loop (you are already testing with the `while`). You should close the file when you are done reading from it.

Comment: You could change `run_again` to `True` .. would be a lot cleaner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think something like that would work. Can't really test now.

```
 run_again = True
    while run_again:
        open_file = input("Please enter name of file: ")
        file_name = open(open_file,"r")
        for line in file_name:
            line = line.strip()
            rows = line.split(" ")
            num = rows[0]
            print(num)

        if input("Would you like to open a new file (yes or no)? ") != "yes":
            print("Have a great day!")
            break
```

Edit :

As suggested by [Blorgbeard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/369/blorgbeard) :

```
    while True:
        open_file = input("Please enter name of file: ")
        file_name = open(open_file,"r")
        for line in file_name:
            line = line.strip()
            rows = line.split(" ")
            num = rows[0]
            print(num)

        if input("Would you like to open a new file (yes or no)? ") != "yes":
            print("Have a great day!")
            break
```

Comment: `while run_again:` may as well be `while True:` and you can remove `run_again`, since you never access it again.